# TypeError at /api/questions/ 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, typeerror

When I go to this *http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/* I get

> **TypeError at /api/questions/**
>
> 'list' object is not callable

### urls.py

(in project)

```
"""QuestionTime URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path

from django_registration.backends.one_step.views import RegistrationView

from core.views import IndexTemplateView
from users.forms import CustomUserForm

# https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.2/activation-workflow.html

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path("accounts/register/", RegistrationView.as_view(
         form_class=CustomUserForm,
         success_url="/",
         ), name="django_registration_register"),

    path("accounts/", include("django_registration.backends.one_step.urls")),

    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),

    path("api/", include("users.api.urls")),

    path("api/", include("questions.api.urls")),

    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),

    path("api/rest-auth/", include("rest_auth.urls")),

    path("api/rest-auth/registration/", include("rest_auth.registration.urls")),

    re_path(r"^.*$", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point"),
]
```

### urls.py

(in appName1/api

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import urlpatterns
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from questions.api import views as qv

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"questions", qv.QuestionViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)), 

    path("questions/<slug:slug>/answers/", qv.AnswerListAPIView.as_view(), name="answer-list"),

    path("questions/<slug:slug>/answer/", qv.AnswerCreateAPIView.as_view(), name="answer-create"),

    path("answers/<int:pk>/", qv.AnswerRUDAPIView.as_view(), name="answer-detail"),

    path("answers/<int:pk>/like/", qv.AnswerLikeAPIView.as_view(), name="answer-like"),
]
```

### views.py

(in appName1/api)
Only showing *QuestionViewSet*

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Question.objects.all()
lookup_field = "slug"
serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

### From the settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
}
```

Error could come from somewhere else.

I don't know where I can find "list".

*appName1 = questions*

Exception Location: *lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py, line 162, in paginator*

Comment: Can you add the code for your viewset `QuestionViewSet` to the question?

Comment: `class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "slug"
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user) ` **To find the code in views.py, it's at the top**

Comment: It's not obvious where the error is from the code you have posted.  Can you add the full traceback to your question and remove all the code that is not related to the error as it just adds noise

Comment: @IainShelvington Which files you need to see?

Comment: The full traceback from the error would be the most useful

Comment: You should include the traceback from the logs not from the debug HTML page. How have you configured the `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` setting?

Comment: You can now see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` setting should be a string not a tuple/list

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    ...
}
```